# Troubleshooting MySQL to MSSQL PHP Query Translation and Speed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Firstly, if this is not the place for this type of question then please let me know and I will delete it.

OK, so I have a MySQL PHP query translation class that translates to MSSQL among other databases. The following test file produces the following results (Debugging enabled)

**Test_File.php**

```
include 'session_handler.php';
include 'database_connection.php';
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM industries LIMIT 5");
```

**MySQL Results:**

```
Query time was 0.00622892379761 seconds for:
SELECT * FROM industries LIMIT 5
Query time was 0.000350952148438 seconds for:
SELECT "session_id" FROM "sessions" WHERE "session_id" = '58'
Query time was 0.000293016433716 seconds for:
UPDATE "sessions" SET "value" = 'x', "expiration" = '0' WHERE "session_id" = '58'
Total query time: 0.00848698616028 seconds
```

**MSSQL Results**

```
    Query time was 0.21740579605103 seconds for:
SELECT
                c.table_schema AS "schema",
                c.table_name   AS "table",                      
                c.column_name  AS "column",
                c.data_type    AS "type"
        FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
        WHERE
                (c.data_type = 'nvarchar' OR
                 c.data_type = 'ntext' OR
                 c.data_type = 'nchar') AND
                c.table_catalog = DB_NAME()
        ORDER BY
                lower(c.table_name) ASC,
                lower(c.column_name) ASC
Query time was 0.21066212654114 seconds for:
SELECT TOP 5 *, CAST("industries"."industry" AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS fmssqln__industry FROM industries
Query time was 0.21116590499878 seconds for:
SELECT "session_id" FROM "sessions" WHERE "session_id" = '58'
Query time was 0.21582698822021 seconds for:
UPDATE "sessions" SET "value" = x, "expiration" = '0' WHERE "session_id" = '58'
Total query time: 1.7053256034851 seconds
```

As you can see the MySQL query is extremely quick, whilst the converted query (converted by the class) take almost 2 seconds.

I don't know anything about the syntax of MSSQL so I am not sure if the converted query is as optimised as it could be?

So my questions are - is the converted MSSQL query a correct translation from the MySQL query, and where should I start to troubleshoot the speed issue?

**Additional Information:**
The MSSQL and MySQL database and tables are identical, content and schema wise.

Thanks

Comment: that session_id in MSSQL is indexed or primary key? Try run this query in QA.

Comment: You need to test that query in some query tool provided by MS. May be PHP MSSQL client lag.

Comment: Ah OK... I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be the driver that PHP is using? Maybe SQL Server is just slower.  Are you using Express? It has limitations on the resources it can use.  Try the queries in SSMS and stick this at the top to get the query timings:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

Limitations of Express are [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx).  So CPU is 1 socket, or 4 cores (which ever is less) and RAM is limited to 1GB.

Comment: I am actually using Azure SQL. I am doing some different tests now using Visual Studio. Thanks for the tip about `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`. Do you know how to get the timings out when doing `sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);` via PHP?

Comment: Hi, after much troubleshooting it turns out to be a latency issue. I have moved all the azure instances to the same location and it is now running at an "acceptable" speed...